# High Memory consumption for ArrayList object

Tags: java, memory-management, arraylist, amazon-s3, jvm

I have created java object (ArrayList of String) which is of size 10^7 into S3. Each entry (String) is of size 13 bytes (12 characters). The size of this file comes around 130MB.

Now when I get the data into ArrayList object from S3 (using AmazonS3Client), the free memory in machine before and after comes around 12090332712 bytes (11.26GB) and 10334207976 bytes (9.62GB) respectively. The difference comes around 1.64GB approximately.

Now the question is memory consumption of ArrayList of String for approximately 15 bytes of size 10^7 shouldn’t be so high as it shows.

Some observations:

- We are streaming the data from S3 to ArrayList object directly. Even
  if ArrayList increases at rate of 1.5 upon reaching current capacity,
  it shouldn’t reach more than 300MB
- Tried using char[] instead of String since char is primitive type and would reduce memory consumption but that isn’t the case either.

Please let me know what am I missing.

Thanks
Adarsh

Comment: How do you measure free memory?

Comment: Could you show some code, how you are performing the operation?

Comment: I would expect a String with 12 chars to take 12*2 = 24 bytes for the char array if it doesn't have excess capacity. Plus a 4 byte reference for the array, plus 4 bytes for the hash variable plus 4 bytes for the string reference. That's about **36 bytes**.

Comment: there may be many reasons for this. maybe you are producing a lot of garbage when you parse the file. also array resize can produce garbage. can you also log gc stats and measure after a full gc?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever `ArrayList` reaches it's current limit a new **much bigger** backing array is created and all of the old items are copied in. This can lead to massive arrays only half-filled.

To avoid this, use a `LinkedList` or measure the count beforehand and create the array with full capacity.

Comment: Even then, each string probably takes ~25 bytes + 4 bytes for the reference in the array backing the list => 300MB. Assuming the array is 1.5x as big as necessary (resizing ratio) that is still only 450MB of memory usage. My guess is that the heap size is increased but not fully used and the OP is looking at the memory usage of the java process itself.

Comment: @assylias - You are right. This issue would not explain the huge discrepancy OP is seeing.

Comment: If I may add, also the process of the copy is relatively slow. You will increase the performance greatly if you know before hand the number of string that you will feed into the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

There is overhead fo each java object. First every object has some header which is 16 bytes on 64bit architecture, maybe more. Secondly String consists of the wrapping object and the containing array. Third each character is represented as two bytes.

Taking all those into account, you probably need at least 64 bytes for each string. Additionally you need array which stores all the strings and another array of half size which was used before array list grew its size. Additionally some temporary objects used for deserialization.

So the overhed is quite big and less data you store the bigger ratio between overhead and the real size you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

"...15 bytes of size" that's your data part. There are other factors.

- Object header: ALl objects in Java record their class
- Object lock: All objects in Java have their own lock, so this takes up space
- char in Java is UTF-16 = 2 bytes
- memory alignment: Objects in memory aren't necessarily laid out compactly. If an object takes just 2 bytes of memory in a 64 bit system, it make actually take up 64 bits (=8 bytes)of memory.

These are just some of the reasons. There may be others.